# Find the last semester using Function LastQuarter + 2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, custom-functions-excel

I need a code that will count how many months was active in the past semester.

I have a pivot and the data changes all the time when the pivot is refreshed, However, I need to calculate the last 6 months average but only using the months that was active in the last semester. e.g
[image]
in this case I would take the average for the last 6 months will only use 4 months (2020 Jan, Feb, Mar & 2019 Dec) because it is the months there person was active in the last semester).

**The rule is the semester start in the month we are now (April) and it goes back 6 months. Apr2020, Mar2020,Feb2020,Jan 2020 & Dec2019,Nov2019** *and from this months we would take the amount only for the 4 months the client as active* like in the image

would it be possible to use

```
Public Function LastQuarter(theDate As Date) As Date + 2 months to get the last semester? 
DateSerial(Year(theDate), 2)+2
```

However, I am guessing I need to use **IF** the last 6 months is = 6 active months in a row **then** go to **code that is already done**

else

But **IF** the last 6 months is < 6 active months in a row **Then** count the number of active months in the last semester *(using the Function LastQuarter(theDate As Date) As Date + 2 months)* and with the total amount of this active months and do the average of the values.
cells(number of active months, 3).value ="Average"

ps: I posted a similar question on https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1227330-how-to-calculate-how-many-months-is-active-in-a-semester/#wcf9?

Comment: How are you determining the last semester?  What are the rules? i.e. Sep-Dec Jan-Apr May-Sep, or something like that?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav The rule is the semester start in the month we are now (like April) and goes back 6 months. Apr, Mar,Feb,Jan,Dec,Nov (it would be the months of the last semester and from this months take the Active months in the pivot) and The active month would be _Mar,Feb, Jan 2020 & Dez 2019_

Comment: if last month is Dec 2019, 6 month is dec,nov,oct,sep,aug,Jul ?

Comment: What mean your LastQuater?  first quarter is 1~3 month.

Comment: @Dy.Lee if the last **active** month is Dec 2019 the last semester would be: April 2020, Mar 2020, Feb 2020, Jan 2020, Dec 2019, Nov 2019. Because the last semester need to started to be count in the Month we are now, in this case, we are in April (so we do 6 months back and check in the pivot the which months was active in this period)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GETPIVOTDATA` function.

Assuming you do not have more than one year of data in the table, given the workbook you downloaded at the other website, for the Amount average for the previous six **existing** months:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Amount in USD",A17,"Transaction Date",MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),{-5;-4;-3;-2;-1;0}))),""))
```

For a non-existent month, the formula returns an error. The `IFERROR` function converts that to a null string, which will be ignored by the `AVERAGE` function.

You can make the obvious changes for Averaging the `Bene Frequency` column, and extending the array constant to include 12 months instead of 6

If you might have more than 12 months in the Pivot Table, then you need to check for  the year also:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Amount in USD",A17,"Transaction Date",MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),{-5;-4;-3;-2;-1;0})),"Years",YEAR(EOMONTH(TODAY(),{-5;-4;-3;-2;-1;0}))),""))
```

[image]

Comment: wow, so instead of a VBA code it would be possible to use a formula. In this case, would a formula work with all changes in the pivot when it is refreshed?  `=AVERAGE(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Amount in USD",A17,"Transaction Date",MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),{-5;-4;-3;-2;-1;0}))),""))` why here is A17 and not C17 would it be bc the pivot starts? However, I notice if I change for C17 or D17 it still works. I did the obvious changes and it works for Bene frequency as well. Maybe would be possible for you to delete the name of the client in your image? seems like I forgot to delete it.

Comment: @Fah The `pivot_table` argument can be **any** cell within the PT. See MS Help for the function for more explanation.

Comment: @Fah Would the formula refresh?  Suggest you try it and see.  And I blanked out the name as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

This is macro an UDF.

```
d5 = AverageSemester()
```

Below is macro.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Semester1 As Variant, Semester2 As Variant
    Dim mySemester As Variant
    Dim Target As Range, rngLast As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Integer, i As Integer

    Semester1 = Array("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct")
    Semester2 = Array("Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)

    With Ws
        r = .Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        Set rngLast = .Range("b" & r).Offset(, 1)
        s = .Range("b" & r)

        If isSemes(s, Semester1) Then
            mySemester = Semester1
        Else
            mySemester = Semester2
        End If
        For i = r To r - 12 Step -1
            s = .Range("b" & i)
            If isSemes(s, mySemester) Then
                Set Target = .Range("b" & i).Offset(, 1)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        .Range("d5") = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(Target, rngLast))
    End With
End Sub
Function isSemes(s As String, vSemester As Variant)
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In vSemester
        If v = s Then
            isSemes = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
Function AverageSemester()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Semester1 As Variant, Semester2 As Variant
    Dim mySemester As Variant
    Dim Target As Range, rngLast As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Integer, i As Integer

    Application.Volatile
    Semester1 = Array("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct")
    Semester2 = Array("Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)

    With Ws
        r = .Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        Set rngLast = .Range("b" & r).Offset(, 1)
        s = .Range("b" & r)

        If isSemes(s, Semester1) Then
            mySemester = Semester1
        Else
            mySemester = Semester2
        End If
        For i = r To r - 12 Step -1
            s = .Range("b" & i)
            If isSemes(s, mySemester) Then
                Set Target = .Range("b" & i).Offset(, 1)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        AverageSemester = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(Target, rngLast))
    End With
End Function
```

### When September is the last data

Average range ~~>  May, Jun, Jul, Aug , Sep

[image]

### When January is the last data

Average range ~~> Nov,Jan

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dy.Lee; However, the date changes all the time and so do the pivot, when the data changes the last ACTIVE 6 months will be different as well. The data is refreshed all the time the workbook is open.

Comment: @Fah, use udf   **Function AverageSemester()** .

Comment: but how about this part `Semester1 = Array("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct")
    Semester2 = Array("Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")` I am sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @Fah, I am not calculating 6 months based on today's date, but I am dividing 6 months based on the last month of the pivot table, judging if this is in the group, and average only the parts corresponding to the group (out of 2) To save. Today is not the standard.

Comment: Dy.Lee, yep, I checked the code and it ` Application.Volatile` does make all the difference. Thank you so much. It is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into EDATE function?

```
=IF([Date you want to check]<EDATE(now(),-6),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: I dont want to check a specific date I need to calculate the average only the month that the client was active in the past 6 months. The rule is the semester start in the month we are now (April) and it goes back 6 months. Apr2020, Mar2020,Feb2020,Jan 2020 & Dec2019,Nov2019 and from this months we would take the amount only for the 4 months the client as active like in the image **the pivot changes all the time_ Edate would only works for the last 6 months and not taking the months it was not active like Apr 2020

Comment: how could I use EDATE Function?

Comment: Sorry for my edits. I was trying to get format right by answering from mobile..

Comment: Combine it with sumif: ` =SUMIF(range,">"&EDATE(NOW(),-6),sum_range)`

Comment: That is the thing I dont want to check the past 6 months in a row (I need to check only the months where the client was active in the last 6 months). In the example above in my pivot I would check 4 months **Mar2020, Feb2020,  Mar2020, Feb2020, Jan 2020 & Dez 2019**

Comment: Where do you know/log the activity?

Comment: I have this code for the past 6 months in a Row (But it is only applicable if the client was active all the past 6 months).
`Sub Last_6_Months_Average()

  Dim lastRow As Long, length As Long
    With Sheet1
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row
        length = Range(.Cells(lastRow - 1, 3), .Cells(lastRow - 1, 3).End(xlUp)).count
        If length > 6 Then length = 6
        .Range("D5").Formula = "=AVERAGE(C" & lastRow - length & ":C" & lastRow - 1 & ")"
    End With
    
End Sub`

Comment: I was think it would be necessary to do something like 
But I am guessing I need to use IF the last 6 months is = 6 active months in a row then CALL  Last_6_Months_Average
else
But IF the last 6 months is < 6 active months in a row Then count the number of active months in the last semester and select the total amount of this active months and do the average of the values.
cells(number of active months, 3).value ="Average"

Comment: The pivot table takes the information from a data sheet. (The excel user will export the data from an online website to excel (12 months data)). and it will be different all the time

Comment: Use `SUMIFS` / `COUNTIFS` with this EDATE idea '>' in the criteria? or add an EDATE column to your data and have this as a selction in the pivot `Cur Semester` Yes or No?

Comment: @nathan_Sav, unfortunately, I can not add any other column to my pivot (however, I could do it in another sheet)  maybe could you give an example of how to do it, I am very clueless how to do it.